# Ask selenium to wait - WebDriverWait issue

Tags: java, selenium, google-chrome, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I am facing an issue with selenium that I could not solve.
I am getting the following error"

```
no such element: Unable to locate element:{"method":"id","selector":"menu-supply-approval-queue"}
```

I know that that the issue is to wait.
So I made the next method:

```
public static WebElement getWebElementByIdWithWait(String id)
    {
        WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(WebDriverMgr.getDriver(), 300000000);
        wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.id("menu-supply-approval-queue")));

        return WebDriverMgr.waitForElementToBeClickable(By.id(id));
    }
```

However selenium not waits, and get this error again:

```
Thu Sep 12 16:56:45 IDT 2019:ERROR: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"id","selector":"menu-supply-approval-queue"}
  (Session info: chrome=76.0.3809.132)
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.36.540470 (e522d04694c7ebea4ba8821272dbef4f9b818c91),platform=Windows NT 6.1.7601 SP1 x86_64) (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)
Command duration or timeout: 0 milliseconds
For documentation on this error, please visit: https://www.seleniumhq.org/exceptions/no_such_element.html
Build info: version: '3.141.59', revision: 'e82be7d358', time: '2018-11-14T08:17:03'
System info: host: '', ip: '', os.name: 'Windows 7', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '6.1', java.version: '1.8.0_65'
Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver
```

Can someone please advise how to make selenium to wait for the element to be displayed/clickable.
it is not waiting a second

what is more odd is that selenium actually returned the element and then clicks on it, so If he can not find it how he returned it?  it just mess with the logs

Here is code that works, however it uses sleep

```
 public static WebElement getWebElementByIdWithWait(String id)
    {
        Logger.sleep(60000);
      //  WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(WebDriverMgr.getDriver(), 8);

     //   wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.id("menu-supply-approval-queue")));

        return WebDriverMgr.waitForElementToBeClickable(By.id(id));
    }
```

regards

Comment: Looks like you are using very old chromedriver.can you upgrade it to 76.

Comment: I assume it's failing on the waitForElementToBeClickable line?

Comment: Show more details about the error. Maybe the stacktrace?

Comment: The odd thing that it is not failing, it just put this in the logs,

Comment: Possible to share url?

Comment: I can not share the URL, sorry. the solution is to use sleep, this is not pretty code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error message...

```
Thu Sep 12 16:56:45 IDT 2019:ERROR: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"id","selector":"menu-supply-approval-queue"}
  (Session info: chrome=76.0.3809.132)
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.36.540470 (e522d04694c7ebea4ba8821272dbef4f9b818c91),platform=Windows NT 6.1.7601 SP1 x86_64) (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)
Command duration or timeout: 0 milliseconds
For documentation on this error, please visit: https://www.seleniumhq.org/exceptions/no_such_element.html
Build info: version: '3.141.59', revision: 'e82be7d358', time: '2018-11-14T08:17:03'
System info: host: '', ip: '', os.name: 'Windows 7', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '6.1', java.version: '1.8.0_65'
Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver
```

...implies that the **ChromeDriver** was unable to initiate/spawn a new **WebBrowser** i.e. **Chrome Browser** session.

Your main issue is the **incompatibility** between the version of the binaries you are using as follows:

- You are using *chromedriver=2.36*
- Release Notes of [*chromedriver=2.36*](https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/2.36/notes.txt) clearly mentions the following :

> Supports **Chrome v63-65**

- You are using *chrome=76.0*
- Release Notes of [*ChromeDriver v76.0*](https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/76.0.3809.126/notes.txt) clearly mentions the following :

> Supports **Chrome version 76**

- Your *JDK version* is **1.8.0_65** which is pretty *ancient*.

So there is a clear mismatch between the *JDK v8u65* , *ChromeDriver v2.36* and the *Chrome Browser v76.0*

---

### Solution

Ensure that:

- *JDK* is upgraded to  current levels [JDK 8u222](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/index.html).
- *ChromeDriver* is updated to  current [ChromeDriver v77.0](https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/index.html?path=77.0.3865.40/) level.
- *Chrome* is updated to  current *Chrome Version 77.0* level. (as per [ChromeDriver v77.0 release notes](https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/77.0.3865.40/notes.txt))
- Execute your `@Test` as **non-root** user.

Answer (score 0):

There is an expected condition elementToBeClickable

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(WebDriverMgr.getDriver(), 60);
        wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.id("menu-supply-approval-queue")));
```

I'm not sure where/what the waitForElementToBeClickable call is doing and why it might be failing.

Comment: Sorry but still no, I put 8 and still selenium not wait.  what is very odd is that selenium return this element and in other method it clicks on it. the problem is just in the logs

Answer (score 0):

The method you posted has a String parameter of id but you hard coded a wait for a specific ID in the second line

```
public static WebElement getWebElementByIdWithWait(String id)
{
    WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(WebDriverMgr.getDriver(), 300000000);
    wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.id("menu-supply-approval-queue")));
                                                             ^ this is hardcoded

    return WebDriverMgr.waitForElementToBeClickable(By.id(id));
}
```

Have you tried removing that line?

```
public static WebElement getWebElementByIdWithWait(String id)
{
    WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(WebDriverMgr.getDriver(), 300000000);
    return wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.id(id));
}
```

If it were me, I would use a method like the below. It's not specific to IDs (you pass in a `By` so it can be used with IDs, CSS selectors, XPath, etc.) and it takes care of the click for you so the wait is specific to clickable.

```
public static void click(By locator)
{
    new WebDriverWait(WebDriverMgr.getDriver(), 15).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(locator)).click();
}
```

You would call it like

```
click(By.id("menu-supply-approval-queue"));
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try "Thread.Sleep(1000);" like

Comment: Hey there. In addition to providing a solution, please explain *why* the answer might solve OP's problem :)

Answer (score -1):

After investigation I found the issue, the Implicit wait was too small.
the soloution:

[image]

Comment: Put implicit wait 25 and explicit  wait 35

Comment: Per [the docs](https://www.seleniumhq.org/docs/04_webdriver_advanced.jsp#explicit-and-implicit-waits), `WARNING: Do not mix implicit and explicit waits! Doing so can cause unpredictable wait times.`